# Run Script execution purpose in xcode run script

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell, run-script

I have a app that uses the shell script that do something during compilation, I am trying to understand what exactly that script do since I am getting compilation error and not able to run the source code.

If someone can help me and explain what below script do

```
#!/bin/bash

echo BUILD_ROOT = "${BUILD_ROOT}"

p=`echo "${BUILD_ROOT}" | sed -ne 's/.*\(^\/.*\/DerivedData\).*/\1/p'`

echo "//${BUILD_ROOT}" > ${SRCROOT}/info.h

cat "${p}/../info.h" >> ${SRCROOT}/info.h
```

I am getting following errors during compilation

> BUILD_ROOT =
>   /Working/XXXXXXX/XXXXX/testTarget/DerivedData/testTarget/Build/Products
>   cat: /Working/XXXXXX/XXXXXXX/testTarget/DerivedData/../info.h: No such
>   file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This script doesn't make too much sense. What are you hoping for it to do? I'll break it down per line:

1. Essentially this does nothing, it's storing the value of `BUILD_ROOT` in itself.
2. By default, Xcode uses `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<YOUR_APP>-XXXXX/...` for its `BUILD_ROOT` variable. This line of code stores the full path of that folder in variable `p`.
3. Creates a file called `info.h` at the base folder of your app's source code with the value of `BUILD_ROOT`.
4. This line is going to the folder above `DerivedData` and printing the value of `info.h` - *which doesn't actually exist and therefore crashing the script* - and appending it to the `info.h` created in line 3.

Comment: Do you have any idea why is it crashing at last? Thanks for your explanation

Comment: It's crashing simply because that file doesn't exist, as I mentioned in step 4.